# Posting form in Laravel 4.1 and blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble posting forms using Laravel 4.1 with the blade template engine. The problem seems to be that the full URL including http:// is being included in the form action attribute. If I hard code the form open html manually and use a relative url, it works OK, however, when it has the full url, I am getting an exception.

routes.php

```
Route::any("/", 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function showWelcome()
{   
    echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    return View::make('form');
}
```

Form opening tag in form.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(["url" => "/","method" => "post","autocomplete" => "off"]) }}
{{ Form::label("username", "Username") }}
{{ Form::text("username", Input::old("username"), ["placeholder" => "john.smith"]) }}
{{ Form::label("password", "Password") }}
{{ Form::password("password", ["placeholder" => ""]) }}
{{ Form::submit("login") }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

So if I go to my home dir / in the browser, I see the form that I have created. If I fill in the form details and click submit, I am simply taken to the same page - the request method is still GET as shown by  echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

I notice that the full

```
http://localhost/subdir/public/
```

url is used in the form markup. If I hardcode a form open tag in such as

```
<form action="/subdir/public/" method="post">
```

it works fine and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] shows as post.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Route::any isn't really good coding practice.  Usually you want to separate the logic for your different request methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the route for the post?

example:

```
{{Form::open(["url"=>"/", "autocomplete"=>"off"])}} //No need to later add POST method
```

in Route.php

```
Route::post('/', 'YouController@postLogin');
```

Comment: Route::any("/", 'HomeController@showWelcome');

That is my only route. I assume the 'any' part means it's both GET and POST routes....

Answer (score 0):

you have not set up a route to handle the POST.  You can do that in a couple of ways.

As pointed out above:

```
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@processLogin');
```

note that if you stick with your existing `Route::any` that the `` `Route::post `` needs to be before it as Laravel processes them in order (I believe).

You could also handle it in the Controller method `showWelcome` using:

```
if (Input::server("REQUEST_METHOD") == "POST") {
... stuff
}
```

I prefer the seperate routes method.  I tend to avoid `Route::any` and in my login pages use a `Route::get` and a `Route::post` to handle the showing and processing of the form respectively.